# Recycleview show wrong data after swipe refresh

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have implemented a RecyclerView with swipe refresh. When swiped, I refresh data by calling an API. But the RecyclerView always show wrong data and different from called API (like duplicate/wrong position)

I'm get answer for adding this code on my adapter, but it not helping. What i did wrong?

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
    return position;
}
```

My Fragment

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (allowRefresh)
    {
        allowRefresh = false;
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    loadRecyclerViewData();

}

public void loadRecyclerViewData(){
//some code
  @Override
  public void accept (List<UnpaidOrder> unpaidOrders) throws Exception
  {
    Log.d("Unpaid Order Fragment", "accept: Data Refreshed");
    mUnpaidOrder.clear();
    mUnpaidOrder.addAll(unpaidOrders);
    mBinding.rvUnpaidOrder.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    if (mUnpaidOrder.size() == 0)
    {
      mBinding.llUnpaidList.showEmptyView(true);
    }
    mBinding.swipeUnpaidOrder.setRefreshing(false);
  }
  //some code
```

Comment: did you debug and check?

Comment: ya i don't get any problem, for the first time loaded it show right data, same like called API give. @KaranMer

Comment: did you check what data is inside your `unpaidOrders` list for second time.

Comment: yeap, it was like the given data from API. nothing wrong @KaranMer